# How to vectorize the `paste` function in R?

Tags: r, text, concatenation, vectorization

Let's say I have a vector of strings (lines) that I scraped from a .txt webpage using `readLines`. Some of the lines will start with "<", generally indicating the start of a new paragraph. Some of the lines will start with a letter, generally indicating that it's connected to the line before it. I want to be able to concatenate lines that belong to the same paragraph.

My plan is to locate the lines that start with "<", and concatenate all the lines in between two lines that start with "<". Essentially, I end up with a list of indices. For example, I may want to concatenate `lines[1:3]`, `lines[4:4]`, `lines[5:9]`, and so on. Is there a way to vectorize this? I cannot just do `paste(lines[begin.index : end.index])`, but that may give you an idea of what I'm hoping to achieve.

Here's some dummy data as an example, since my actual data is too long:

```
[1] "<P> sampletextsampletext"
[2] "sampletextsampletext</P>" 
[3] "<P> sampletext"
[4] "sampletext"
[5] "sampletext</P>"
[6] "<P> sampletext </P>"
```

I would want to concatenate lines 1 and 2 together, and likes 3, 4, and 5 together, and line 6 will stay the same.

Comment: Please include a sample of your data. Your problem isn't very clear from the description alone.

Comment: You have to understand that asking "how to vectorize paste()" sounds very odd to R folks because paste() _is_ vectorized. Maybe you're just looking for the `collapse` argument?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have groups of lines (1:3, 4:4, 5:9) and you need to know how to apply `paste` with a `collapse` argument to each group. `dplyr` or `data.table` are your friends here, though `aggregate` would probably work just fine.

Comment: @Gregor you are exactly right! Would you be able to show me how it'd be done using any of those optiosn?

Comment: If you share your sample data with `dput()` so it's copy/pasteable and also share with `dput()` your list of indices, sure, I'll take a look. I really dislike data entry so you've got to do the legwork for me.

Comment: why would you even need to do this? this is html.. `paste0(x, collapse = '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to separate HTML nodes, it's better to use functions that understand HTML. This has the advantage of keeping you from needing to manually find start and end tags, too.

```
# read in data
lines <- c("<P> sampletextsampletext",
           "sampletextsampletext</P>" ,
           "<P> sampletext",
           "sampletext",
           "sampletext</P>",
           "<P> sampletext </P>")

# load a simple HTML scraping/parsing package
library(rvest)

# find all `<p>` tags and their contents
lines %>% paste(collapse = '') %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('p')
# {xml_nodeset (3)}
# [1] <p> sampletextsampletextsampletextsampletext</p>
# [2] <p> sampletextsampletextsampletext</p>
# [3] <p> sampletext </p>
```

Comment: thank you for this answer! I was originally using rvest but was running into difficulties. I guess I just don't know how to use it correctly. When I tried this method on my data, I got the error `Error: Name d:2qwt is not XML Namespace compliant [202]`. Have you seen anything like that before?

Comment: I can't really help without seeing the relevant part of the data, but really, `readLines` is a bad way to import HTML, which is likely the issue. Instead, pass `read_html()` a URL or filepath to read the data directly as HTML. There's a chance it's actually just malformed HTML, but make sure it's not your process before you go searching through hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a base R solution. The two grep operations deliver the starting and stopping lines for paragraphs to the `mapply`-administered function to collapse them together with `paste`:

```
> txt <- scan(what="")
1: "<P> sampletextsampletext"
2: "sampletextsampletext</P>" 
3: "<P> sampletext"
4: "sampletext"
5: "sampletext</P>"
6: "<P> sampletext </P>"
7: 
Read 6 items
> grep("<P>", txt)
[1] 1 3 6
> grep("</P>", txt)
[1] 2 5 6
> mapply( function(x,y) paste( txt[x:y], collapse=" "), grep("<P>", txt), grep("</P>", txt) )
[1] "<P> sampletextsampletext sampletextsampletext</P>"
[2] "<P> sampletext sampletext sampletext</P>"         
[3] "<P> sampletext </P>"
```